# Outputting first n elements in the list

Tags: list, recursion, f#

How do you write a f# recursive function that accepts a positive integer n and a list xs as input, and returns a list containing only the first n elements in xs.

let rec something n xs =
..
something 3 [1..10] = [1;2;3]

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is:  Don't, just use `Seq.take`.

A simple version would be something like:

```
let rec take n list = 
  match n with
  | 0 -> []
  | _ -> List.head list :: take (n - 1) (List.tail list)
```

A tail-recursive could look like:

```
let rec take n list =
  let rec innertake m innerlist acc = 
    match m with
    | 0 -> List.rev acc
    | _ -> innertake (m - 1) (List.tail innerlist) ((List.head innerlist) :: acc)
  innertake n list []
```

Note that neither of these does anything to handle the case that the input list is shorter than the requested number of items.

Comment: What about last 3 elements?

Comment: The _easy_ way would be to reverse the list, run `take` on the new list, and then reverse the result.  Better/more efficient ways would be out-of-scope for this question and should be answered in a seperate question.